# How to see the error pointed out by FireBug

Tags: firebug

In the top right hand corner is a 2 which shows the error count bu nowhere does it show you what the actual error is?? I want to use FireBug to step into javascript

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
    <style>
     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
     pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
     .version {color: gray;}
     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
        <br><br>

        <b> Requested URL: </b>/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js<br><br>
```

the above is just part of the html.
what on earth is going on here?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Net" tab to start and observe the response. Check also what was sent, headers, etc.

`data` might be `null`. In that case you will never pass the `IF`

Comment: I found it: but does not know what it means. I clicked on the net tab and expanded GET jquery.dataTables.min.js then clicked on the Response tab and it gives a 404 Not Found. please see OP for the HTML please.